# How do I get the value of a nested formBuilder group

Tags: forms, angular, typescript

My nested form is currently formatted in this way:

```
this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      user:  this.formBuilder.group({
        id: ['', Validators.required],
        name: ['', Validators.required],
        phone: ['', Validators.required]
      })
})
```

I would usually access the value like this:

```
let userID = this.Form.controls['id'].value;
let userName = this.Form.controls['name'].value;
let userPhone = this.Form.controls['phone'].value;
```

but because the formGroups are nested, I'm not sure how to access the nested values. I tried:

```
let userName = this.Form.controls['user'].name;
```

What's the correct syntax for accessing a form control value in a nested formGroup? Thanks

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/AbstractControl-class.html#!#get-anchor

Comment: Oh thanks! the doc definitely helped. This example from the doc really helped:

    `this.form.get(['person', 'name']);`

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I was able to access the value by doing the following:

```
let userName = this.Form.controls['user'].value.name;
```

or

```
let userName = this.Form.get(['user','name']).value;
```

Either one works.

Answer (score 11):

As of Angular 4+ you can do the following:

`const userName = this.form.get('user.name').value`

In fact, you can chain it up through the whole length of your nested form e.g:

```
this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      parent:  this.formBuilder.group({
               child: this.formBuilder.group({
                      grandChild: this.formBuilder.group({
                                  grandGrandChild: ['',Validators.required],
                            }), 
                      }), 
               }),
})
```

And then access the value like this:

`this.form.get('parent.child.gradChild.grandGrandChild').value`

Answer (score 5):

This is doesn't work in Angular 6+

```
this.form.get(['person', 'name']);
```

But you can use

```
this.form.get('name').value;
```

I don't know why the first variant doesn't work for me, because in the documentation we can see that the get method expects an array of ..

```
get(path: Array<string | number> | string): AbstractControl | null
```

I am so sorry for my mistake, you can use something like this to get value from nested control:

```
this.layerSettingsForm.get('name.styleName').value;
```

Comment: thats my terrible mistake... If you have nested formGroup, you can you something like 
    this.layerSettingsForm.get('name.styleName').value);

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
let userId = this.form.value.id
```

Answer (score 2):

Old post, but just found a different solution.

`let userName = (this.Form.controls['user'] as FormGroup).controls['name'].value;`

If user is undefined or null, userName will also be null on result and not crash.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me

```
form.controls['workWeek'].value.dayGroup.fridayAM
```

Answer (score 1):

In Angualr 8, in the HTML template:

`form.get('user').get('id')`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
const formValue = this.form.controls.user.controls;
let userId = formValue.id.value;
let userName = formValue.name.value;
let userPhone = formValue.phone.value;
```

this idea basically works for any nested forms