# How do I set the value of a nested formBuilder group

Tags: forms, angular, typescript, angular2-forms, angular-reactive-forms

My nested form is currently formatted in this way:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.user = this.fb.group({
    name: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2)]],
    quest1: ['', Validators.required],
    account: this.fb.group({
      email: ['', Validators.required],
      confirm: ['', Validators.required]
    }),
    questions: this.fb.group({
        quest2: ['', Validators.required],
    }),
  });
}
```

I would usually set the value like this:

`this.user.controls['quest1'].setValue('false');`

But because the formGroups are nested, I'm not sure how to set the nested values.

How do I set a value for "quest2"? What's the correct syntax for set a form control value in a nested formGroup?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can do it using the syntax below:

```
this.user.get('questions.quest2').setValue(false);
```

Note that `setValue` *method* throws an *error* if some control is missing. So, if you don't want to update all controls, you can use `patchValue`:

```
this.user.get('questions.quest2').patchValue(false);
```

or

```
this.user.get(['questions', 'quest2']).patchValue(false);
```

or

```
this.user.patchValue({questions: {quest2: false}});
```

Comment: Many thanks man! It worked here. I used it like this:

This.user.patchValue ({questions: {quest2: 'false'}});

Comment: this.user.get(['questions','quest2']).patchValue(false); will work also. Inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40934763/how-do-i-get-the-value-of-a-nested-formbuilder-group. Angular 5+

Comment: @r0b3rt0 yep, the `get` method is really flexible :)

Comment: It didn't work for me, it replaces the formgroup with the value.