# How to pre-set a checkbox in FormBuilder of an Angular Reactive Form & enable/disable a button based on that checkbox

Tags: angular

I am trying to enable / disable a button on my Reactive Form in my Angular app based on whether or not a checkbox is checked.

**Expected Result:**
When the page loads, the checkbox should be unchecked, & the button should be disabled.
The button is only enabled if the checkbox is checked.

Here is the code in my TS file:

```
this.emailForm = this.fb.group({
    conditions: new FormGroup({
        acceptTerms: new FormControl(false, Validators.requiredTrue),    
        })
})
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="acceptTerms">Accept:</label>
    <checkbox
        formControlName="acceptTerms"
        id="acceptTerms"
        heading="Accept"
        name="acceptTerms"
        value="Accept">
    </checkbox>
</div>

<button button
    class="btn"
    type="submit"
    title="Submit"
    data-kind="primary"
    [disabled]="emailForm.controls['acceptTerms'].invalid>
    Submit
</button>
```

**Actual Result:**
With this actual code, I'm not able to check the checkbox & the button is also enabled on page load.

Can someone please tell me what changes I need to make so that I get the expected result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this with the below code:

**TS:**

```
this.emailForm = this.fb.group({
    conditions: new FormGroup({
        acceptTerms: new FormControl(false, Validators.required)
    })
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<button
    [disabled]="emailForm.controls['conditions'].controls['acceptTerms'].value === false">Next
</button>
```

With this, when the page loads the checkbox is unchecked & the button is disabled. When I check the checkbox, then the button is enabled.

If I un-check it again, the button is disabled again.

Answer (score 0):

I would jut listen for changes to the element and set a variable and then bind it to the disabled property

```
 let isChecked = false;

  this.emailForm.get(['conditions','acceptTerms']).valueChanges.subscribe(val => {
      isChecked = val ? true : false;
  });

<button
    class="btn"
    type="submit"
    title="Submit"
    data-kind="primary"
    [disabled]="!isChecked">
    Submit
</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I made a mistake with my code, & have updated it above. The _acceptTerms_ checkbox is actually inside a nested form group (_conditions_). I was trying to access it without going into the nested form group. Can you tell me how to do so? Here is what I'm trying to do in pseudo-code: `[disabled]="emailForm.controls['conditions'].acceptTerms.invalid">`

Comment: please refer to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40934763/how-do-i-get-the-value-of-a-nested-formbuilder-group

Comment: I changed my code based on this article.  I would be curious to understand if it would actually work :)