# Angular Reactive Forms - submit a form of 2 dimensional array

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-forms

I am using Angular 9.

I have the following:

**approval-edit.component.html**

```
<mat-card class="approval-edit-card-nominated">
    Nominated Evaluators
    <div>
        <form class="approval-edit-form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(approvalEditForm)" #approvalEditForm="ngForm">
            <table *ngIf='nominationAllOf'>    
                <tr *ngFor="let nomination of nominationAllOf; let i = index">
                    <div *ngIf='i > 0'>&nbsp;&nbsp;and</div>
                    <div class='nomination-row' *ngIf='nomination'>
                        <td *ngFor="let item of nomination.nominations; let j = index">
                            <div class="nomination-wrapper">
                                <div class="nomination-or" *ngIf='j > 0'>or&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
                                <div class="nomination-evaluator">
                                    <div class="example-full-width">
                                        <input name="UserName{{i}}{{j}}" id='userName{{i}}{{j}}' type="text" matInput value='{{item.evaluatorInfo.personalInfo.name.firstName}}&nbsp;{{item.evaluatorInfo.personalInfo.name.lastName}}'>
                                    </div>      
                                </div>
                            </div>                      
                        </td>
                    </div>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <button *ngIf='nominationAllOf' mat-raised-button>Update</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</mat-card>
```

And

**approval-edit.component.ts**

```
  public nominationAllOf: NominationAllOf[];


      public onSubmit(formValue: NgForm): void {
        console.log(formValue);
      }
```

As you can see, I have a `nominationAllOf` object that I iterate over and populate the `input` items.  This displays as expected.

[image]

I am populating the list via a 2-dimensional array (`NominationAllOf[]`).

**nomination-allof.ts**

```
export interface NominationAllOf {
    nominations: NominationAnyOf[];
}
```

**Problem**

I can get the 'Update' button to call the `onSubmit` function, but I am not sure how to extract the `input` values. I would like them to populate an updated `NominationAllOf[]` object.

**Question**

On calling the `onSubmit` function, how do I pass through the `input` values for each item?

I tried to use a formGroup, but I wasn't sure given that the `NominationAllOf[]` is not simple. So the object submitted does not matter what format it is, as long as I can use it to populate the updated `NominationAllOf[]` when it is submitted in javascript.

Comment: In your use case I would go with reactive form and use `FormGroup` with `<form [formGroup]="approvalEditForm">` . after you defined your `FormGroup` you can easily access all the values, also the nested one like in your case. for example: `submitForm() { this.approvalEditForm.controls['your form control name'].value}` EDIT: here you can find how to access nested values: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40938001/2976876

Comment: Thanks, I am giving what you suggest a go, but I get errors. `<form class="approval-edit-form" [formGroup]="approvalEditForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">` and in the component I have: `public approvalEditForm: FormGroup;`. But I get the following error:  `Error: formGroup expects a FormGroup instance.`.

Comment: Do I need to create a new formGroup with all the field names? (With a blank formGroup, 
 `this.approvalEditForm = new FormGroup({ });`, I get the following error:  `ERROR Error: Cannot find control with name: 'UserName00'`)

Comment: you need to instantiate it with `new` for example: `profileForm = new FormGroup({
    username: new FormControl('')
  });`

Comment: yes, you need to define all inputs so you can access it later in other method call.

Comment: The problem is, in the `new FormGroup(` constructor, I don't have access to `this`.  How do I set the names (which are dynamic depending on the size of the array).

Comment: Is there are way to submit a form, not using a formGroup?

Comment: Check this for creating dynamic forms: https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#creating-dynamic-forms